# Почему powershell отправляет 195 и 191 вместо 255?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

Занимаюсь разработкой проекта, но возникла проблема.

Пытаюсь отправить с клиента (Powershell) Яна сервер (Python) картинку в байтовом представлении, отправляю пиксели в формате RGB. К примеру вот что отправляет клиент если отправить чёерную картинку 2х1:

`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Думаю смысл понятен.
Но при отправке числа 255 клиента отправлеяет `[195, 191]`, при отправке 130 клиент отправляет `[194, 130]`, но при отправке 123 и ниже отправляет само число(т.е. `[123]`).

Немного почитав, нашёл что это байты utf-8 и попробовал такой код для расшифровки:

```
def clean_packet(packet):
    answer = []

    decoded_packet = packet.decode('utf-8')

    for byte in decoded_packet:
        print(byte, len(decoded_packet))
        answer.append(ord(byte))

    return answer
```

Однако, код возращал на кучу байт меньше оригинала. Есть ли какие догадки как же можно конвертировать байты? Или же уже были похожие вопросы? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Вот код powershell для отправки пикселей:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;

        $imagePath="$env:temp\microsoft-log-desktop\test.png";
        $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($imagePath);

        $bytes = @();

        for ($x = 0; $x -lt $bitmap.Width; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y -lt $bitmap.Height; $y++) {
                $pixel = $bitmap.GetPixel($x, $y);

                $red = $pixel.R;
                $green = $pixel.G;
                $blue = $pixel.B;
                
                $bytes += $red;
                $bytes += $green;
                $bytes += $blue;
            }
        }
        Write($bytes.Length);
        $packet = [byte[]]@(5) + $bytes;
        $messageToSend = PackPacket($packet);
        $writer.WriteLine($messageToSend, 0, $messageToSend.Length);
        $writer.Flush();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: WriteLine записывает символы, а не байты, так что код отправки можно считать чушью. А ещё я не нашёл что такое PackPacket

Comment: Понял, функция PackPacket добавляет байты длины пакета в начало, так что это никак не повлияло бы на отправление данных. То есть в итоге мне нужно использовать дургой отправщик данных а не запись в стрим?

Comment: Ну так нефиг слать бинарные данные как текст...

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось и вправду когда я использую $writer.WriteLine() он пишет символы. Я просто заменил на $socket. Вот исправленный код:

powershell

```
$server_port = 1336;
$server_ip = '127.0.0.1';

$socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket(
    [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork,
    [System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream,
    [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp
);

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;

        $imagePath="$env:temp\microsoft-log-desktop\test.png";
        $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($imagePath);

        $bytes = @();

        for ($x = 0; $x -lt $bitmap.Width; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y -lt $bitmap.Height; $y++) {
                $pixel = $bitmap.GetPixel($x, $y);

                $red = $pixel.R;
                $green = $pixel.G;
                $blue = $pixel.B;

                $bytes += $red;
                $bytes += $green;
                $bytes += $blue;
            }
        }
        Write($bytes.Length);
        $packet = [byte[]]@(5) + $bytes;
        $messageToSend = PackPacket($packet);
        $socket.Send($messageToSend);
```

всем спасибо за ответы!